# MS5611 sends additional byte after NACK

Tags: stm32, i2c

I'm currently try to use the MS5611 (sitting on a CJMCU-117) over I²C with libopencm3 on a STM32F103C8.

When I do a read, the slave sends an additional byte (0xFF) after the master has send a NACK. This happens for the PROM readout (2 bytes) as well as for the ADC readout (3 bytes).

The following Code results in the following waveform, the datasheet [1] shows on page 13 how it should look like.

```
// Send
i2c_transfer7(I2C2, 0x77,
    commandPtr, 1,
    nullptr, 0);

// Read
i2c_transfer7(I2C2, 0x77,
    nullptr, 0,
    bufferPtr, 3);
```

[image: Waveform]

Can anybody help me how to solve this?

[1] https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=showdoc&DocId=Data+Sheet%7FMS5611-01BA03%7FB3%7Fpdf%7FEnglish%7FENG_DS_MS5611-01BA03_B3.pdf

Comment: Check your code. It looks like the master is doing an additional read, that is not an issue with the device being addressed.

Comment: The slave does not send anything by itself. It's the master that clocks the extra byte. Typical STM32F1xx coding error by the way, people asked about this on various STM32 forums at least 10 years ago already.

Comment: Thanks guys, that makes sense. Since I was just relying on the i2c_transfer7 function of libopencm3, I couldn't really see room for error there. But now I had a look at it and it seems like it is not following the protocol of the reference manual. I implemented it myself now and this seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The i2c_transfer7 function of libopencm3 is implemented using I2C with polling, but isn't following the STM32 Reference manual (RM0008, Page 759, Method 2), which states special handling of 1 and 2 byte receives. This results in clearing the ACK-bit at the wrong time.

See http://libopencm3.org/docs/latest/stm32f2/html/i2c__common__v1_8c_source.html#l00492

Comment: That is not an answer.  Not behaving *how*?  What is the difference between what it is doing vs. what the reference manual says it should be doing??